# Apply softmax on a subset of neurons

Tags: keras, softmax

I'm building a convolutional net in Keras that assigns multiple classes to an image. Given that the image has `9` points of interest that can be classified in one of the three ways I wanted to add `27` output neurons with softmax activation that would compute probability for each consecutive triple of neurons.

Is it possible to do that? I know I can simply add a big softmax layer but this would result in a probability distribution over all output neurons which is too broad for my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the most naive implementation, you can reshape your data and you'll get exactly what you described: "probability for each consecutive triplet".

You take the output with 27 classes, shaped like `(batch_size,27)` and reshape it:

```
model.add(Reshape((9,3)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Take care to reshape your `y_true` data as well. Or add yet another reshape in the model to restore the original form:

```
model.add(Reshape((27,))
```

---

In more elaborate solutions, you'd probably separate the 9 points of insterest according to their locations (if they have a roughly static location) and make parallel paths. For instance, suppose your 9 locations are evenly spaced rectangles, and you want to use the same net and classes for those segments:

```
inputImage = Input((height,width,channels))

#supposing the width and height are multiples of 3, for easiness in this example
recHeight = height//3
recWidth = width//3

#create layers here without calling them
someConv1 = Conv2D(...)
someConv2 = Conv2D(...)
flatten = Flatten()
classificator = Dense(..., activation='softmax')

outputs = []
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        fromH = i*recHeight
        toH = fromH + recHeight
        fromW = j*recWidth
        toW = fromW + recWidth
        imagePart = Lambda(
                           lambda x: x[:,fromH:toH, fromW:toW,:], 
                           output_shape=(recHeight,recWidth,channels)
                          )(inputImage)

        #using the same net and classes for all segments
        #if this is not true, create new layers here instead of using the same
        output = someConv1(imagePart)
        output = someConv2(output)
        output = flatten(output)
        output = classificator(output)
        outputs.append(output)

outputs = Concatenate()(outputs)

model = Model(inputImage,outputs)
```